# In PyQt5, matplotlib's FigureCanvasQTAgg in QScrollArea is not working fine

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating an application with `PyQt5`.

I want to add a chart with long width, so I tried to add the graph into a `QScrollArea`.

I wrote the code below using `FigureCanvasQTAgg` of `matplotlib`

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QScrollArea
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.resize(400, 300)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    fig.set_size_inches(30, 1)
    figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    scroll = QScrollArea(widget)
    scroll.setWidget(figure_canvas)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But when I scroll it, it is not working fine.

The gif shows the situation when I scroll to right.

[image]

Is there any advice for the code?

My python is `python 3.6.0`

And I am using `matplotlib 3.0.3`, and `PyQt5 5.12.2`

My computer is MacBook Pro 15-inch Mid 2014,

and the os is Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to update your version of my matplotlib module >3.2.0rc1.
This version contains a correction for that issue  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14160.
I tested it on my computer and it works well.